# Using Bash to replace words from one list with random words from other list in a very large text file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, sh

I have a very long text file, let's call it `longstory.txt`.

There's a set of words I want to replace, which is in the file `badwords.txt`.

There's another set of words that I want to replace all the bad words with, `goodwords.txt`.

The catch is that I want to do it randomly, so that every single instance of a word from `badwords.txt` will be replaced with a random word from `goodwords.txt`.

My first thought was to just use the following code to essentially find every instance of every bad word and replace it with a random good word.:

```sh
for i in $(cat ./badwords.txt); do
    for j in $(grep -o $i outputstory.txt); do
        sed -i "s/\([^A-z]\)$j\([^A-z]\)/\1$(shuf -n1 ./goodwords.txt)\2/" outputstory.txt
    done
done
```

To make a long story (pardon the pun) short, I underestimated just how long the story is. In order to replace every instance of every bad word, `sed` would need to scan through a little under 1.5 million lines and over 25 million characters.

I left it running for 24 hours and it didn't even get past the 3rd word. I've never been very good at efficiency, but considering there's 720 more words I feel like I'll probably die in a freak accident before the script is finished.

Is there any better way to do this? Should I not be using Bash in the first place? I'm open to anything!

Comment: Do you want all occurrences of a bad word to be replaced by the same good word, or do you want to randomly pick a good word for each occurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting `gawk` (standard `awk` in most Linux) script.

Scanning `longStory.txt` file once.

Replace all bad words per line.

Each substitution takes random good word.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {
  while (getline < inp1) badWordsArr[++badWordsCount] = $0;
  close(inp1);
  while (getline < inp2) goodWordsArr[++goodWrodsCount] = $0;
  close(inp2);
} 
{
  for (badWord in badWordsArr) while( sub("\\<"badWordsArr[badWord]"\\>", goodWordsArr[1 + int(rand() * goodWrodsCount)]));
  print;
}
```

#### running

```
awk -f script.awk -v inp1="bad-words.txt" -v inp2="good-words.txt" longstroy.txt
```

### Explanations:

#### Reading `bad-words.txt` into array `badWordsArr`

```
  while (getline < inp1) badWordsArr[++badWordsCount] = $0;
  close(inp1);
```

#### Reading `good-words.txt` into array `goodWordsArr`

```
  while (getline < inp2) goodWordsArr[++goodWrodsCount] = $0;
  close(inp2);
```

Length of array `goodWordsArr` stored in variable `goodWrodsCount`

#### Gettin random index for `goodWordsArr`

Array index start with `1` up to `goodWrodsCount`

```
1 + int(rand() * goodWrodsCount)
```

#### Getting random good word from array `goodWordsArr`

```
goodWordsArr[1 + int(rand() * goodWrodsCount)]
```

#### Substitute single occurrence of current `badWord` in current line

```
sub("\\<"badWordsArr[badWord]"\\>", goodWordsArr[1 + int(rand() * goodWrodsCount)])
```

#### Substitute all occurrence of current `badWord` in current line

Each substitution provide different random `goodWord`.

```
while( sub("\\<"badWordsArr[badWord]"\\>", goodWordsArr[1 + int(rand() * goodWrodsCount)]))
```

#### Matching all `badWrods` in current line

```
for (badWord in badWordsArr) ...;
```

#### printing modified current line

```
print
```